# Recursion check whether a series of operations yields a given number

Tags: javascript, recursion

In the book Eloquent JS in the section of recursion, a program was given:

> Consider this puzzle: by starting from the number 1 and repeatedly
>   either adding 5 or multiplying by 3, an infinite amount of new numbers
>   can be produced. How would you write a function that, given a number,
>   tries to find a sequence of such additions and multiplications that
>   produce that number? For example, the number 13 could be reached by
>   first multiplying by 3 and then adding 5 twice, whereas the number 15
>   cannot be reached at all.

I have following program which look like checks it, but I don't know how to make it print he sequence.

```
function tester (value, key) {
    if (value == key) {
        return 1;
    }

    else if (value > key) {
        return 0;
    }

    else {
        if ( tester(value+5, key) || tester(value*3, key) ) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: What are your inputs to this function?  It seems there should only be one...

Comment: @ScottSauyet The input is value = 1 always. Key is the number to be checked. There are no default parameters in Js

Comment: There are default parameters in JS, and have been for a while.  If that's what you want, you could write `function tester(key, value=1) { /* ... */ }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your version is a little odd to me, returning `1` or `0` rather than `true` or `false`.  Are you mostly used to a language that conflates booleans with such integers?  But it looks like it should work.

I would write it a bit differently.  I generally prefer my recursion to count down to smaller inputs.  You can write a simple function to test the values like this:

```js
const m3a5 = (n) => n < 1 
  ? false 
  : n == 1
    ? true
    : m3a5(n - 5) || (n % 3 === 0 && m3a5(n / 3))

console.log(m3a5(13)) //=> true
console.log(m3a5(15)) //=> false
console.log(m3a5(18)) //=> true
```

This should be entirely equivalent to yours, modulo the boolean/int differences.

With this one, you can can then expand it in a fairly straightforward manner to allow you to capture the steps:

```js
const m3a5 = (n, steps = []) => n < 1 
  ? false 
  : n == 1 
    ? steps
    : m3a5(n - 5, ['+5'].concat(steps)) 
      || (n % 3 === 0 && m3a5(n / 3, ['*3'].concat(steps)))

console.log(m3a5(13)) //=> ['*3', '+5', '+5']
console.log(m3a5(15)) //=> false
console.log(m3a5(18)) //=> ['*3', '+5, '+5', '+5']
```

Note that this will show one possible path, not all of them.  For instance `['+5', '*3']` is another possible result for `m3a5(18)`, one which you would get by switching the main branch to

```
: (n % 3 === 0 && m3a5(n / 3, ['*3'].concat(steps))) 
  || m3a5(n - 5, ['+5'].concat(steps))
```

But if you want *all* the paths, that would be significantly different code.

Comment: Wow, excellent answer! I like ternary operators very much and your implementation looks really cool :3

Comment: The conditional (ternary) operators are for me mostly a way to use expressions rather than statements as much as possible in my code.  I've almost entirely stopped using `for`, and I'm getting closer on `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You could store the sequence and if found the calculation return the sequence.

```js
function tester(key, value = 1, sequence = value) {
    if (value > key) {
        return false;
    }

    if (value === key) {
        return sequence;
    }

    return tester(key, value + 5, '(' + sequence + ' + 5)')
        || tester(key, value * 3, sequence + ' * 3');
}

console.log(tester(15));
console.log(tester(11));
console.log(tester(24));
console.log(tester(37));
```

Comment: I like your output format... almost.  Why did you choose to parenthesize only the addition?  It feels slightly odd, if legitimate.  Obviously you couldn't do only the multiplication, for distribution reasons.  But both seems clearer.  And I'm trying to decide whether I like this better than my array notation of the steps.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, it's just to keep the operator precedence.

Comment: Right.  That's what I meant to describe when I said "for distribution reasons".  But I find, for instance, the output of `tester(37)` harder to read than I would `(((((1 * 3) * 3) * 3) + 5) + 5)`, but perhaps that's just me.